# Why is this OCaml code resulting in a runtime error?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to run the following code on a coding question website and it says there is a runtime error, but running it on the top-level ocaml seems to work fine. Could there be any source of error in the code? Thanks in advance

The question is to find the number of 'good segments' within the given list and a specific number. A good segment is defined as follows:

1. A and B are positive integers such that A < B.
2. x that satisfies A <= x <= B is not an element of the given list.

The following are the inputs.

1. n, which is the number of elements in the list that will be given.
2. a, b, c, ... which are the elements of the list.
3. t, which is the number that must be included in the segment.

The output should be a single number printed out.

### Edited Code:

```
let rec drop_value l to_drop =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | hd :: tl ->
    let new_tl = drop_value tl to_drop in
    if hd = to_drop then new_tl else hd :: new_tl
;;

let rec find_start li t cur_min =
  match li with
  | [] -> cur_min
  | hd :: tl -> let new_min = abs (t - hd) in 
  if new_min = 0 then find_start tl t new_min 
  else if new_min < cur_min && t > hd then find_start tl t new_min 
  else find_start tl t cur_min
;;

let rec find_end li t cur_min =
  match li with
  | [] -> cur_min
  | hd :: tl -> let new_min = abs (t - hd) in 
  if new_min = 0 then find_end tl t new_min 
  else if new_min < cur_min && t < hd then find_end tl t new_min 
  else find_end tl t cur_min
;;

let rec contains_value l value =
  match l with
  | [] -> false
  | hd :: tl -> if hd = value then true else contains_value tl value
;;

let nums = ref [];;
let n = read_int () in
for i = 1 to n do
  Scanf.scanf " %d" (fun a -> 
    nums := a :: !nums)
done;

Scanf.scanf " %d" (fun t ->
  if contains_value !nums t then print_int 0
  else let start = if List.length !nums = 1 then 1 else abs (find_start !nums t 1001 - t) in 
  let finish = find_end (drop_value !nums start) t 1001 + t in
  if t > start && t < finish then (if start = 1 && List.length ! nums = 1 then print_int ((t - start + 1) * (finish - t) - 1) else print_int ((t - start) * (finish - t) - 1)) 
  else let start = 1 in print_int ((t - start + 1) * (finish - t) - 1))
;;
```

eg.

5

4 8 13 24 30

10

should give

5

=> [9, 10], [9, 11], [9, 12], [10, 11], [10, 12]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't describe the exact input format that your code is going to get. This makes it pretty much impossible to debug your code.

When I compile and run your code (as `m.ml`) using the input you describe I see this:

```
$ ./m
5 4 8 13 24 30 10
Fatal error: exception Failure("int_of_string")
```

In fact no matter what format I try for the input I get the same result.

So that is probably what is happening at the website.

In my experience it always causes more harm than good to use `scanf`. Combining it with other input functions is probably going to make things worse.

If you describe the expected format of the input carefully, somebody on StackOverflow can recommend a way to get your numbers.

In the meantime here's a way to read all the numbers on one line:

```
 let rec split_at list n =
     if n = 0 then
         ([], list)
     else
        match list with
        | [] -> ([], [])
        | h :: t ->
            let (a, b) = split_at t (n - 1) in (h :: a, b)
 in

 let (nums, t) =
 let line = read_line () in
 let nstrs = Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \t][ \t]*") line in
 match List.map int_of_string nstrs with
 | [] -> failwith "no numbers"
 | n :: rest ->
      if List.length rest <> n + 1 then
          failwith "bad count"
      else
          let (nums, tlist) = split_at rest n in
          (nums, List.hd tlist)
in
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you sir for an informative answer. I am debugging my code right now. Now the code is running without runtime error (I used " %d" instead of "%d " for scanf, I don't know what difference it is though). But I am still failing some unknown test cases.. I have fixed my code above.

Comment: Glad to hear you're making progress. A space in a `scanf` format says to skip any amount of whitespace (tabs, newlines, spaces) at that point. This is one of the things that makes `scanf` impossible to use. But if you get it working, more power to you.

Comment: I am very new to OCaml and am much used to C style coding. Is it okay to define multiple functions separately like I did above in my code? Is it a conventional way to write OCaml codes? I am really not sure if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: Your code looks fine, I can read it. It is completely normal to define functions like you're doing. For what it's worth the `;;` token isn't very often used in OCaml source code. It's almost always used only interactively, to tell the REPL (the "toplevel") when to evaluate what you've typed so far. But you *can* use it in source code if you insist and some people do.

Comment: Thank you I have fixed the problem and thank you for your feedback. I hope I can get more help in the future from you. Thank you sir!

Comment: I'm around much of the time, happy to help when I can.